# Bootstrap Font Awesome Social Buttons not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'm using a template for my website, but now I'm trying to change the buttons for Social Media. If I specify the color in a class (for example `btn btn-primary`) the button changes its color. But only with the `btn btn-social btn-twitter`it gets transparency. I assume this is related with the Bootstrap template is using.

My question is: is there some way of forcing button's color while using the btn btn-social btn-twitter object?

This is my code:

```
<div class="call-to-action">
    <h4 class="mb-5">Mamá Quiero Ser Científica</h4>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h5>Follow us on our Social Media</h5>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/mqscientifica" class="btn btn-social btn-twitter waves-effect waves-light" rel="nofollow">Twitter <span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/Mam%C3%A1-Quiero-Ser-Cient%C3%ADfica-748273108707351/" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook waves-effect waves-light" rel="nofollow">Facebook <span class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a target="_blank" href="https://www.instagram.com/mqscientifica/" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-instagram waves-effect waves-light" rel="nofollow">Instagram <span class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is what my buttons look now: [image: they have the same color as the footer, and I want them with their own social color]

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what the problem is and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @ovokuro look at the edit I just did, I posted an image of how my buttons look now, and what I want is to force the color so they would be blue and pink like the social media they represent. Thanks :)

Comment: Try giving ( color:blue;) etc.  in CSS. It will change accordingly.

Comment: @VipulTyagi I tried, but is not working. Besides, I want to preserve the btn-social appearance, but it is not working!!

Comment: Add a new class and add some specificity, bootstrap has a downfall or a very good perk (depends on how you want to look at it) which is that it's very specific when applying css to its elements. Make sure the CSS rule you're using to apply color is very specific.

Answer (score 1):

The object you are trying to edit has multiple classes:

```
class="btn btn-social btn-twitter waves-effect waves-light"
```

This means that that object is a btn, a btn-social, a btn-twitter etc etc.

This classes are referenced in the css that you are using (Likely Bootstrap or Material design), so a possible solution would be to find the btn-twitter in your css and change the color there.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the icons inside `<i>` tags and provide the color value to the `<i>` tag in the CSS. Hope this helps. 
eg:

CSS:

```
`<style>
   i{ color:red;}
 </style>

 <i class="social fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> `
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if the color I want is the one from the social button!?? It is different everytime